# Install a .terminal file to change Terminal color scheme - Ubuntu Gnome

Tags: gnome, themes, gnome-terminal

I found the [`One Dark` Terminal color scheme](https://github.com/nathanbuchar/one-dark-terminal) and I'm in love with it, but it only provides a `.terminal` file. I know that`.terminal` files are what OSX uses to theme its Terminal, but so far I've been unable to find literature on how to use a `.terminal` file to change the scheme of an Ubuntu Gnome terminal.

I'd appreciate some instructions on how to do so.

Thanks much,

goldage5

Comment: Why would a settings file for a Mac work on Linux?

Comment: I was hoping that there was some tool to parse it into a settings file that Ubuntu can use, or if there was some way to convert it myself.

Comment: Which version of Gnome Terminal are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problems with those themes is they are in Apple's (probably proprietary) format. So you have to decode bits and pieces to find what is used.

You can get the RGB value of each color in [this itermcolors version of the theme](https://github.com/nathanbuchar/one-dark-terminal/blob/master/scheme/one-dark/One%20Dark%201.0.1.itermcolors), or perhaps [the original Atom theme](https://github.com/atom/one-dark-syntax) - you should then be able use the colour info from those to edit the profile colors:

[image]

To some extent, you can also decode some other sections of the theme using base64 - e.g. to find the font by decoding [this bit](https://github.com/nathanbuchar/one-dark-terminal/blob/8929fe003469e2f29b5b0bcb7324db3908fa6d41/scheme/terminal/One%20Dark%200.7.0.terminal#L1310-1318):

```
$ echo "YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGGBlYJHZlcnNpb25YJG9iamVjdHNZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3AS
AAGGoKQHCBESVSRudWxs1AkKCwwNDg8QVk5TU2l6ZVhOU2ZGbGFnc1ZOU05hbWVWJGNs
YXNzI0AkAAAAAAAAEBCAAoADXxAVU291cmNlQ29kZVByby1SZWd1bGFy0hMUFRZaJGNs
YXNzbmFtZVgkY2xhc3Nlc1ZOU0ZvbnSiFRdYTlNPYmplY3RfEA9OU0tleWVkQXJjaGl2
ZXLRGhtUcm9vdIABCBEaIy0yNzxCS1JbYmlydHZ4kJWgqbCzvM7R1gAAAAAAAAEBAAAA
AAAAABwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADY" | base64 -d ; echo
bplist00�X$versionX$objectsY$archiverT$top��U$null� 


VNSSizeXNSfFlagsVNSNameV$class#@$��_SourceCodePro-Regular�Z$classnameX$classesVNSFont�XNSObject_NSKeyedArchiver�Troot�#-27<BKR[birtvx�����������
```

From that we can guess the font is Source Code Pro (Regular).

---

I also found [this](https://github.com/seenaburns/osx-terminal-themer) which may be able to convert the theme to a json format, the issue is it needs `libplist` integrated with python to work:

```
$ python ./osxterminalthemer.py --convert json ./One\ Dark\ 0.7.0.terminal 
/bin/sh: plutil: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./osxterminalthemer.py", line 284, in <module>
    thm_data = unpackage_theme(thm_data)
  File "./osxterminalthemer.py", line 150, in unpackage_theme
    v_plist = plistlib.readPlistFromString(v_plist)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/plistlib.py", line 103, in readPlistFromString
    return readPlist(StringIO(data))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/plistlib.py", line 78, in readPlist
    rootObject = p.parse(pathOrFile)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/plistlib.py", line 406, in parse
    parser.ParseFile(fileobj)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

This script was probably made for Mac where the appropriate libraries are available, but I could not get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the repository you link to, also provides an [itermcolors](https://github.com/nathanbuchar/one-dark-terminal/blob/master/scheme/iterm/One%20Dark%200.7.0.itermcolors) file, which appears to have more easily readable data within it. You could parse the floating point values out, and convert them to appropriate hex values for use in the palette setting for a `gnome-terminal` profile.